# Understanding gradle distribution

Tags: gradle

In a chapter 7.3.4 of [Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:examples) said about distribution:

> We also add a distribution, that gets shipped to the client:

There is also provided a source code:

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    dependsOn spiJar
    from 'src/dist'
    into('libs') {
        from spiJar.archivePath
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}

artifacts {
   archives dist
}
```

So I'm trying to add it in my build script but it doesn't work of the reason:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':MP'.
>   Could not find property 'spiJar' on task ':MP:dist'.

Could you explain in a nutshell where it'd be really helpful to use distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular sample demonstrates how a standalone Java application could be shipped as a Zip file. To run the sample, you'll have to get its full source code, which is included in the `samples` dir of the `gradle-all` download.